# Silverlight WPF Generic Data Item

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Basically I use lists to display information, these lists contain custom data items I have created, they all look similar and have some of the same controls in them, essentially they need to look the same colour, font etc. At the moment, I just seem to be repeating code over and over each time a change is needed i.e. colour. 
I have been wondering if it would be a good idea to create a generic data item which all the lists use and then just collapse controls which aren't needed.

So I was going to create a user control called something like "GenericDataItem". This data item will contain all the controls that each data item would need, then use dependency properties to collapse controls not required.

My question is would this be the right way to go about this, or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but arent you just looking for datatemplates. can you provide some code or some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got the point, but [using](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) could help you.